# Rxjava2, Retrofit2 - transfer data between two classes.

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have simple Observable.

```
public interface CitiesApi {
    @GET("location/cities")
    Observable<List<City>> getCities(@Query("country") String countryId);
}
```

Also i have two classes:

```
class Manager {

List<City> mList = new ArrayList();

public Observable<List<City>> getCitiesObservable(String countryId) {
// I want to update mList value in each new request;
 return CitiesApi.getCities(countryId);
}
```

Second class:

```
class Presenter {

    public void request() {


    Manager.getCitiesObservable("us")
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread)
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
           .subscribe(new ......)
        }
```

As you can see, i wrote a comment "I want to update mList value in each new request".
How can i update mList in Manager class each time when Presenter makes a request ??

Comment: Did you `Serialize` the response you get from that request ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I will post an answer with the way I do it, maybe you'll understand better

Comment: Ok. I'm waiting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use transforming operators of RxJava (like `map`) to achieve what you want to do. Here's a list of all operators - [ReactiveX - Operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)

And here's how you can do it:

```
class Manager {

    List<City> mList = new ArrayList();

    public Observable<List<City>> getCitiesObservable(String countryId) {
        return CitiesApi.getCities(countryId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(new Function<List<City>, List<City>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<City> apply(List<City> cities) throws Exception {
                        // Do your stuff and return a List<City> object
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I promised:

Consider you set the adapter and prepared your `mList`, I do it this way.
The function that calls the request and put the response body in a variable

```
private void makeGetMyChatsRequest(String searchWord){
    RestClient.getApi().getChats(searchWord).enqueue(new Callback<Chats>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Chats> call, Response<Chats> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                if (response.code() == 200){
                    chatsDatas = response.body().getChats();
                    chatAdapter.notifiDataSetChanged();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Chats> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "-=onFailure=-\n" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the retrofit interface

```
@GET(RestClient.API_GET_CHATS)
Call<Chats> getChats(@Query("username") String username);
```

And the `type` of object it responds, in my case `<Chats>`

```
public class Chats implements Serializable {
private ArrayList<ChatsData> chats;

public ArrayList<ChatsData> getChats() {
    return chats;
}

public void setChats(ArrayList<ChatsData> chats) {
    this.chats = chats;
}
}
```

And because I had an array of data, I also defined the type of data inside this array(that exact data that will be passed to `chatsDatas` variable on the request call function.

```
public class ChatsData implements Serializable {
private int chat_room_id;
private int read;
private int user_id;
private String name;
private String picture;
private int is_online;
private LastMessageData last_message;
//here will be getters & setters for each field
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it with rxjava. I want that my class Manager takes data, which class Presenter will receive

Comment: Ok, but the idea of updating the list should be the same, you get the new data and set it again to the list

Comment: I understand. But you do it with one class, what if i have more than 20 managers ?? Your code looks not universal and without rx. 
I want that my class manager will be similar like this


 
return CitiesApi.getCities(countryId).doOnNext (SAVE DATA IN CLASS MANAGER) ;

Comment: Pfff.. You want to save data in the class manager.. That doesn't sound right for me.